Does WPF not run GC and destroy objects on application exit?
I am working on a WPF application. I had noticed that destructor (finalizer in c#) of the class is not being hit when application is closed. Also I had noticed that IDisposable.Dispose method was not automatically hit. However when I call dispose method of an object on application exit, then the dispose method is hit.
I just want to know the reason behind it. Why WPF does not run GC and dispose the objects? Is memory freed by OS upon application exit?

The CLR runs finalizers at AppDomain unload, with a 2 second timeout to deal with a deadlocked finalizers.  Not terribly uncommon for COM rcws btw.  AppDomains were removed for .NETCore (aka .NET 5 and up), that also removed the finalizer guarantee.  You can subscribe the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit event to do cleanup, that one still works.

And IDisposable.Dispose is not "automatically" hit. It's the consumer (developer) of an IDisposable that is responsible for calling it, either explicitly or by wrapping the disposable object in a using statement.

Thank you both. I had got the same from my own research for GC and IDisposable, but was getting confused because someone was saying that IDisposable hits automatically

Call GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers() on exit of your application
